# aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 function is failing with a complex PGSQL query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, plpgsql

I setup the pgsql CVS export using AWS Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-examples

When I use the shown example in the doc (creating a dummy table and enter some dummy values) and call that sql query from the aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 function, its working flawlessly:

```
SELECT * from aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select * from sample_table', aws_commons.create_s3_uri('s3_bucket', '/path/filename)
```

Instead of the the simple table query, if I use complex pgsql where we curated it to pull reports from combining different tables (the query has single quotes in it), its throwing a syntax error at the singles quotes (') that are part of the query we are using:

> select dev.integer, 'Feburary', EXTRACT('DAY' from dev.integration_eed), te.timber_upperclass, count(*) from uer_auth ua, team_id gm where ua.id = gm.user_id and gm.group_id in (select id from groups where org_id not in (select id from fi)) and dev.integration_eed >= '2023-02-01 00:00:00' and dev.integration_eed < '2023-03-01 00:00:00' group by dev.integer, EXTRACT('DAY' from dev.integration_eed), te.timber_upperclass;

Any clue on why its not accepting single quotes within the function call??

The error basically comes where we have the month inserted in single quotes (for example 'February' is in single quotes):

```
`ERROR: syntax error at or near "Feburary" LINE 1: ...from aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select ua.scope, 'Feburary',...`
```

Answer (score 1):

The quotes need to be escaped. Either change the quotes inside the query to be two consecutive quotes, e.g. `''February''`, or use dollar-quoted strings around the query that is passed to `aws_s3.query_export_to_s3`, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
  FROM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3(
    $$SELECT dev.integer,
             'Feburary',
             EXTRACT('DAY' FROM dev.integration_eed),
             te.timber_upperclass,
             COUNT(*)
        FROM uer_auth ua,
             team_id gm
       WHERE ua.id = gm.user_id
         AND gm.group_id IN (SELECT id
                               FROM groups
                              WHERE org_id NOT IN (SELECT id
                                                     FROM fi))
         AND dev.integration_eed >= '2023-02-01 00:00:00'
         AND dev.integration_eed < '2023-03-01 00:00:00'
       GROUP BY dev.integer,
                EXTRACT('DAY' FROM dev.integration_eed),
                te.timber_upperclass;$$,
      aws_commons.create_s3_uri('s3_bucket', '/path/filename)
```

(see [4.1.2.4. Dollar-Quoted String Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING))

Of the two approaches, dollar-quoting is usually more readable and more maintainable.